# iPhone does not work well with header with CSS?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I've developed an web-application that uses CSS as well. Here's is how my GUI looks like initially. This is the perfect GUI i wanted.

[image]

However after a while, the GUI becomes like that within 3second of loading the page.

[image]

This is the HTML of my header.

```
<div id="Slideshow">
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" style="width:100%; height:150%">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var step = 1
function slideit() {
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image" + step + ".src")
    if (step < 5)
        step++
    else
        step = 1
    setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
}
slideit()
//-->
```

I added the `style="width:100%; height:150%"` only to just resize the image but not the entire header. Therefore, for my phone, i added a separate CSS like this

```
#Slideshow
{
    position:absolute;
    height:15%;
    top:10%
}
```

I resize the `150%` to `height:15%` in the CSS. Unfortunately, this problem only happen on iPhone but does not happen on a samsung android phone.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's cause by the  height of container (#Slideshow) calculating by iPhone is different the other phone.
Have you tried to use this one?

```
<img src="image/s1.jpg" name="slide" style="width:100%; height:auto">
```